# How to adjust my floating bar when minimized

Tags: javascript, css, blogger, sidebar

Right now the code below floats to the left side of the content and it's visible when you scroll down. So far everything is Okay as long as the window is maximized. But when it's minimized or you increase the zoom the bar shows over the content which I don't want it to. In these cases (minimized window and increased zoom) I'd like the bar to be stuck to left margin so it won't be shown over the content. Obviously the bar must keep being floating to the left and visible when scrolled down (if the window is maximized). What changes do I need to do to accomplish this? Thank you very much for your support in advance!

```
#pageshare 
{
position:fixed; 
bottom:15%; 
right:10px; 
float:left; 
border: 1px solid #5c5c5c; 
border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
background-color:#e5e5e5;
padding:0 0 2px 0;
z-index:10;}

#pageshare .sbutton 
{
float:left;
clear:both;
margin:5px 5px 0 5px;
...
}
```

Comment: It is difficult to understand the problem without more code. Please add your HTML, a link to a live site, or reproduce the problem using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: I added the javascript tag to this question because I don't believe there is a cross-browser way to do this with CSS only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using JavaScript to modify the attributes of both the main site container as well as the `pageshare` container. For simplicity, I utilized [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

**Adjust Site Margin ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ArGKd/3/))**

I created a method that adjusts the site margin based on the amount of space needed by the `pageshare` container. First, this method calculates the amount of space needed for the `pageshare` container (based on its width and its left offset) and the amount of space available (the site width subtracted from the window width, normalized to zero if negative). The method then calculates the difference between these two values and applies the value to the left margin of site container. This ensures that the `pageshare` container does not overlay the content. In addition, the reason I am setting and removing `scroll` event handlers is because otherwise the `pageshare` container will still appear over the content on a small window when you scroll left and right ([example of issue](http://jsfiddle.net/ArGKd/2/)).

```
function adjustSiteMarginForPageShare() {
    // Get the window dimensions
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    // Get the site width
    var siteWidth = $('#inner-wrapper').outerWidth();
    // Get the pageshare dimensions
    var pageshareWidth = $('#pageshare').outerWidth();
    var pageshareHeight = $('#pageshare').outerHeight();
    // Get the pageshare left offset
    var pageshareLeft = $('#pageshare').offset().left;

    // Calculate the needed pageshare space
    var pageshareSpaceNeeded = pageshareWidth + pageshareLeft;
    // Calculate the available pageshare space (division because of centering)
    var pageshareSpaceAvailable = (windowWidth - siteWidth) / 2;
    // Ensure the minimum available pageshare space as zero
    pageshareSpaceAvailable = (pageshareSpaceAvailable > 0) ? pageshareSpaceAvailable : 0;

    // If the pageshare space available is less than what is needed
    if (pageshareSpaceAvailable <= pageshareSpaceNeeded) {
        // Calculate the left margin needed as the difference between the two
        var leftMarginNeeded = pageshareSpaceNeeded - pageshareSpaceAvailable;

        // Add the left margin needed to the site
        $('#inner-wrapper').css('margin-left', leftMarginNeeded);

        // Modify the pageshare style
        $('#pageshare').css({
            'position': 'absolute'
        });

        // Set the pageshare scroll behavior
        $(window).off('scroll.pageshare');
        $(window).on('scroll.pageshare', function() {
            // Set the bottom to top conversion factor (100% total height - 15% bottom offset = 85% top offset)
            var conversionFactor = 0.85;
            // Calculate the top offset based on the conversion factor and the pageshare height
            var pageshareTopOffset = (conversionFactor * windowHeight) - pageshareHeight;
            // Adjust the pageshare top offset by the current scroll amount
            pageshareTopOffset += $(window).scrollTop();

            $('#pageshare').css({
                'top': pageshareTopOffset + 'px',
                'bottom': 'auto'
            });
        });

        // Trigger the pageshare scroll handler
        $(window).triggerHandler('scroll.pageshare');
    } else {
        // Reset the pageshare style
        $('#pageshare').css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'top': 'auto',
            'bottom': '15%'
        });

        // Turn off the pageshare scroll behavior
        $(window).off('scroll.pageshare');
    }
}
```

The last step is to call that method, both on page load and every time the window is resized.

```
// Adjust the content margin for pageshare container on load
adjustSiteMarginForPageShare();

// When the window is resized
$(window).resize(function () {
    // Adjust the content margin for the pageshare container
    adjustSiteMarginForPageShare();
});
```

Comment: Wow that is too much for a tiny bar and even if everything is well-explained I do not get it. Good job amigo Ruben! (yeah también soy latino) so now I guess I just have to replace the codes but I do not know where exactly... could you please guide me the way? Thank you very much in advance and keep up the good work!!

Comment: @user2074499 You just need to include the JavaScript code in your website. You can learn more at [W3Schools JS How To page](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_howto.asp). Keep in mind the code I used utilizes [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/), so you will need to include that first! If this answer ends up helping you with your problem, please make sure to accept and/or upvote the answer.

Comment: Checking the code in Blogger it is located before </body> so I think I have to replace it to the 2 codes you gave me. About jQuery I guess I need to add <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/> to have it running in my blog... Before your last comment I added your codes and it said there was an error (Blogger does not let you save changes if it finds an error) and this time I need to do many changes without a tutorial just for adjust a floating bar. I messed with it twice and had a really hard time trying to fix it...

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I really appreciate them. If you do not mind please check out my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14945779/how-to-adjust-my-floating-bar-when-minimized I think it is a piece of cake compared to this. I hope you can help me. Nos vemos!